# Why can't I pickpocket Babette?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I have seen on in several places that it is possible to pickpocket trainers after training with them.  Is there a list of pickpocketable trainers?  I tried to do this with Babette in the Dark Brotherhood... but when I go into sneak mode... it seems I am unable to pickpocket her as when I place the crosshairs over her it shows nothing.  Are there only certain trainers this works with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Children are not valid pick-pocket targets in Skyrim - Babette isn't pick-pocketable because she's a child vampire, not because she's a trainer per se.

Pick any other trainer, and you'll be able to recoup your expenses.